# Ms Word and its fancy quotes breaks string compare

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word

I am using win32com.client in python to open a word process, open a doc, and compare some text to the python variables that I have in my code.

For example:

I have in my code:

```
HeaderName = 'xyz'
```

I open the word doc and access the header text:

```
self.HeaderTable = self.doc.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.Tables(1)
self.HeaderName = self.HeaderTable.Cell(1,1).Range.Text
```

and then I compare the two and print out pass or fail

```
if HeaderName == self.HeaderName:
    print('Pass')
else:
    print('Fail')
```

The issue is when the header contains a double quote. Ms Word uses fancy quotes and this breaks my string compare.

```
>>> chr(8220)
'“'
>>> chr(8221)
'”'
>>> chr(8220) == '"'
False
>>> chr(8221) == '"'
False
```

Any ideas on how I should proceed? I even tried replacing all the fancy quotes with regular quotes, but word just reverts back to the fancy ones. I dont want to do the following because I do a lot of string comparisons and dont want to go and change every individual one unless thats the only solution.

```
if headerName == self.HeaderName.replace(chr(8220), '"').replace(chr(8221),'"'):
    print('Pass')
else:
    print('Fail')
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I used a function called ReplaceQuotes to replace it to some crazy character combination. Changed my code to replace all double quotes in strings to that crazy character combination and then compared them.

```
def ReplaceQuotes(self):
    wdFindContinue = 1
    wdReplaceAll = 2

    # Note self.word is the instance of the Word application

    self.word.Selection.Find.Execute(chr(8221), False, False, False, False, False, True, wdFindContinue, False, '!(0_0)!', wdReplaceAll)
    self.word.Selection.Find.Execute(chr(8220), False, False, False, False, False, True, wdFindContinue, False, '!(0_0)!', wdReplaceAll)
```